# Could this be a scam

Tags: banking, scams, money-transfer, fraud, transfer

I'm asking a couple questions for a friend because I think he is being scammed.
Is it possible to receive a check of a very large amount into a banking system (ILC group), but for you to receive it asks you to link your card details for transaction. There was no routing number to link accounts and when he linked his card to the account it asked for a OTC code.
Is this a scam or is this possible?

Comment: since you're a new user, I'd like to note that this question being closed is not an indication that it's a "dumb" question - this site is just designed around the idea of having one canonical question / answer, rather than seeing the same question multiple times. Please read the linked question -- **it suggests your friend is indeed being scammed** -- and upvote the question / answer if they are useful to you. Welcome to the site!